# Three LEDs on consecutively with different time intervals

Tags: voltage, transistors, power, current, resistors

The title is referring to [a youtube video if a 555 and CD4017 led larson scanner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETHB7nzrTWk) but this circuit only allows the LED to be on at the same time interval.

Is there a circuit which can help to activate three LEDs consecutively for different time intervals. For example, LED 1 will on for 3s (the other 2 LEDs will be off), followed by LED 2 will be on for 2s (the other 2 LEDs will be off), then finally LED 3 will be on for 5s (the other 2 LEDs will be off) and this cycle repeats itself.

Comment: Johnson counter will easily count to 10 with OR gates with a 1 Hz clock like 3,2,5...s

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, hi sir, do you mind if you could show me a schematic of it if you are not busy  :) ?

Comment: i'm busy, would you like to think about it design it

Comment: @catherinetan A twisted ring johnson counter made from 5 FFs provides 10 states. If you light up LED 1 when the last three FFs are 0 and light up LED 3 when the last FF is 1 (tie LED 3 directly to last FF) and light up LED 2 otherwise, then you have it.

Comment: @jonk, hi sir, can this be used for each different time interval that each  led will light up or just for the same time interval for all led light up?

Comment: @catherinetan [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKTNf.png) ***only*** works for your single, concrete example as given in the question. If you change the problem, the logic changes. If you want a generic solution where you can program in the period and the timing, then you have an MCU or else some kind of "plug-board" computer.

Comment: @jonk, thank you for answering, I understand better now :)

Comment: @catherinetan No problem. The above circuit would be clocked with a 1 second clock rate at the clocking input. In any case, all this is just a matter of sitting down with a piece of paper and knowing a few things. The twisted ring johnson counter is NOT always the better approach. You could do the same thing with four, not five, FFs. But the optimization problem takes a little time, by hand, then. (There are many good solutions, but probably only a few optimal ones and it is a matter of checking all the permutations to find them.) There are also other tools to use in those cases.

Comment: @jonk, I am recently new to this Johnson Counter. I never encountered them before because I do not have any electrical background at all. I read some article saying Johnson Counter will be able to provide very precise synchronization :)

Comment: @catherinetan Johnson counters are one shape among many shapes. Broadly, your job is to acquire as many mental tools of general utility as you can in a lifetime so that you have more than a few ways to solve the exact same problem. You do NOT want to only know how to use a hammer and then have to force every problem to become a nail for it. Instead, become a skilled carpenter who knows a great many ways to get something done and can take a look at a given problem and find the better option for the customer/client. So knowing about johnson counters is good. But do not reach for it all the time.

Comment: @jonk, hi sir, sorry to bother again, I have simulated your circuit in LT Spice. Is the output (at red dot in picture ) correct ? I have attach my answers in the answer section

Comment: @catherinetan You need 'bubble inputs' as shown on my schematic. Or add inverters. Look back at my schematic. Do you know what it means to see little circles on the inputs of a gate?

Comment: @jonk, oh so the tiny tiny red dot are all inverters ? Sorry, it is too small haha

Comment: No no! The little bubbles ***behind*** the gates!! (Circles)

Comment: @jonk, right , got it :)

Comment: Since nobody has said it already: doing this with a MCU would be trivial.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, refering to your picture again at https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKTNf.png, this circuit will on the led consectively from beginning to end then beginning to end and this cycle repeats itself. However, if I want to light the led from beginning to end and then from end to beginning (reverse direction) and the cycle continues. May I ask how to implement that? Is it possible with D-flip flop also?

Comment: @jonk, refering to your picture again at https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKTNf.png, this circuit will on the led consectively from beginning to end then beginning to end and this cycle repeats itself. However, if I want to light the led from beginning to end and then from end to beginning (reverse direction) and the cycle continues. May I ask how to implement that? Is it possible with D-flip flop also?

Comment: Naturally if you make a simple change with any logic spec, it can be realized in a similar way, but why change the question now? For LEDs ABC # in seconds like 3A = 3s on A, you now want(?) 3A 2B 5C 2B, 3A 2B 5C 2B (?)  or repeat each end  (?) What is your real purpose?

Answer (score 1):

The typical NE555 circuit has a timing capacitor that will be discharged by a resistor connected to pin 7 and charged by another resistor connected to the positive supply. You can modify (shorten) the charge time with additional current from the outputs of the johnson counter.

Connect each counter output with a different series resistor and a diode to the timing capacitor of the NE555. The diodes are needed to avoid current flow back to the inactive outputs.

Use resistors in the range 2 kohm to 100 kohm for a first attempt and use a larger timing capacitor, because this method produces only individual shorter clock periods.

[image]

Comment: Could you add a schematic of that? Even a pseudo one?

Comment: @Passerby just added

Comment: Ah, parallel the led output with the wire going to the discharge pin.

Comment: @Passerby D1-D3 are not LEDs! You add them to the outputs, so you decide how bright they will be. Do not take more than 4 mA, CD4017 has weak drive strength.

Answer (score 1):

The 10 off 15k resistors isolate the 4017's outputs from each other as well as providing base drive for the transistors. The transistors are basically acting as NOR gates, if any input to a transistor's base resistor is high then that transistor's collector is pulled low turning on an LED.

The 680R resistors limit LED current to about 10mA.

The 7555 is running at just about 1 Hz.

[image: LED Driver]